# Set range with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a worksheet of qualified persons which search the each range in row (each row is a person, columns are different qualifications), to find out if the the range is empty, if not, the name of the person will be added into the list.

The question is why `rng = Worksheets("Q Matrix").Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 8))` is not taken by the program and reported as error 1004?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lastr As Long, lastr1 As Long
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastr = Worksheets("Auditorenliste").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastr1 = Worksheets("Q Matrix").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 6 To lastr1
rng = Worksheets("Q Matrix").Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 8)) 'range("E" & i & ":G" & i)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
    Worksheets("Auditorenliste").Cells(lastr1, 2).Value = Worksheets("Q Matrix").Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to use the Set keyword while setting the range. Try it like `Set rng = Worksheets("Q Matrix").Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 8))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Set keyword to set the value of an object variable.:

```
set rng = Worksheets("Q Matrix").Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 8))
```

Comment: I just tried, it works, the error reporting is gone, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec Actually, you missed one - it needs to be `Set rng = Worksheets("Q Matrix").Range(Worksheets("Q Matrix").Cells(i, 5), Worksheets("Q Matrix").Cells(i, 8))`

Comment: @P.Schlegel If it works, please consider marking it as answer to close the question. (Tick mark left of the question.) Also, take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).